# How to Group by id and Order By count in Django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I'm having trouble converting writing the correct Python script that does what I can accomplish in `MYSQL`

Below is the SQL query that accomplish exactly what I want. Where I get tripped up in `python` the the `GROUP BY` statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(story_id) AS theCount, `headline`, `url` from tracking
GROUP BY `story_id`
ORDER BY theCount DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Here's What I have in `python` so far. This queries all of the articles just fine, but it's lacking any kind of `groupby()` or `order_by()` based on `COUNT`.

```
articles = ArticleTracking.objects.all().filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date))[:20]

article_info = []    
for article in articles:
    this_value = {
        "story_id":article.story_id,
        "url":article.url,
        "headline":article.headline,
        }

    article_info.append(this_value)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use aggregation.

```
articles = ArticleTracking.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date))
articles = articles.values('story_id', 'url', 'headline').annotate(count = Count('story_id')).order_by('-count')[:20]
```

Also go through the aggregation documentation in Django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 1):

Don't try this at home.

You can add a group_by clause to a queryset like this:

```
qs = ArticleTracking.objects.all().filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date))
qs.query.group_by = ['story_id']
articles = qs[:20]
```

This is not part of the public api, so it may change, and it may work differently (or be unavailable) depending on the particular db backend you're using. Worth mentioning that I'm not sure if applying the group_by clause before or after the filter makes any difference. I have had success with this with a MySQL backend, though.

Comment: So I'm confused, should I do his or not? I'm just looking for the standard way of doing this.

Comment: This will get it done, and so will using raw SQL. Django doesn't officially support GROUP BY, so choose your favorite work-around.